# Docker doesn't make services available by default

Tags: php, mysql, docker, memcached, docker-compose

I've been wrestling with docker for the last 2 days and read numerous pages on the official docker website, and on stackoverflow, but everything I read only seems to add to the confusion. Not only because the syntax of the docker-compose.yml file seems to change with every version.

I've gotten to the point where I managed to get my website running with the following configuration, but there's a few major issues.

Services don't seem to be available where you expect them to be.

Every time I restart docker (docker-compose up) I have to make sure the IP address didn't change of my MySQL container. When it changes, I need to change my code so that it connects with the correct server. This creates an unusable environment.

After I finally figured out that I can make MySQL work by selecting some obscure IP address for the connection (172.18.0.x), my next problem is memcached also being available inside the PHP container. Changing the IP address here to the obscure docker IPs is not going to look very good in my GIT repository as well.

Is there any way to solve this problem universally, instead of having to deal with the same obscurity every time I add a service?

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
    memcached:
      image: memcached:alpine
      container_name: gok_mamcached
      ports:
        - "11211:11211"
      expose:
        - 11211

    mysql:
      image: mysql:5.7
      container_name: gok_mysql
      environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=database
        - MYSQL_USER=user
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
      ports:
        - "3306:3306"
      expose:
        - 3306
      restart: always

    php:
      image: wildscamp/php
      container_name: gok_php
      environment:
        - TIMEZONE=Asia/Hong_Kong
      ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
      working_dir: /var/www/html
      links:
        - mysql
      restart: always
```

Please help me get out of this nightmare.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By default every container is connected to every other container within a single docker network, thanks to internal docker DNS. And this is your case, since, by default, all docker-compose services in a single compose file are created within a "default" network named (%currentdirectoryname%_default).

All you actually need to do is to address the other container correctly. The most straightforward and logical way to do it - is by the **services name** *mysql*, just like you named it in your compose file.

You can also address another container is by its hostname if you set it, or even by its container id if you are so inclined.

The awesome bonus of that is that if you happen to use docker swarm and scale your service to many instances, they will still all be available behind that same single server name and simply get round-robin'd on each call. So you don't have to come up with hostnames for every service.

**P.S.**:
Please don't use links, as explicit changes nothing, is deprecated and is ignored in swarm mode.

If you want to express dependency, use `depends_on`. It works quite well with `healthcheck` to additionally ensure the correct start-up sequence.

Comment: Hey, Yereth! Sorry I missed you on my last KM trip! One other thing—I strongly recommend putting your db connection info in evironment variables rather than hardcoding in your repo. Makes local development and other ad-hoc stuff way easier. Go read about the 12-factor app if you haven’t already: http://12factor.net